# Getting an input field's type using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please disregard this. There was an error in my script and I was looking on here for 15 minutes.

How do you find the type of an input field only using Javascript?

Per say you have these input field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm" value="Y"/>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" />
```

How do you find the those field's input `type`?

Comment: Oooh I was getting an error in my script. That's why it wasn't working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain Javascript:

```
var type = document.getElementById('confirm').type;
```

jQuery:

```
var type = $('#confirm').attr('type');
```

Answer (score 7):

It's as simple as:

```
var type = document.getElementById("confirm").type
```